# How to write an asynchronous program with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

Lets say, for example, I want to write a nodejs program where I have two or three independent parts like fs.readdir, fs.copy, etc. on different locations, but the result all three actions is to be sent to a json file like this:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

var jsd = {
    "act1" : false,
    "act2" : false,
    "act3" : false
}

fs.readdir(path1, function (err, files) {
    if (err)  jsd.act1 = err;
    for (x in files)  console.log(files[x]);
    jsd.act1 = true;
});

fs.copy(path2, path3, function (err) {
    if (err)  jsd.act2 = err;
    jsd.act2 = true;
});

fs.remove(path4, function (err) {
    if (err)  jsd.act3 = err;
    jsd.act3 = true;
});

// all three of the above actions are independent, so it makes sense that all of them are executed asynchronously.
// Now we write jsd object to a json file; jsd's contents are dependent on the above actions though

fs.writeJson("./data.json", jsd, function (err, files) {
    if (err)   return console.error(err);
});
```

How do I make sure that the correct data is entered into the file **data.json**, i.e fs.writeJson executes after the actions previous to it are executed first?

I know one way is to nest all of them, i.e,

```
readdir() {
  copy() {
    remove() {
      writeJson();
    }
  }
}
```

But this may result in callback hell, so is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to do this in the async way? This does not mean you're doing things in parallel. You can use the sync version of those fs functions and make it more simple.

Comment: promises. have you looked into promises?

Comment: yea, I know about synchronous versions of those, but then I won't be using the asynchronous properties of these, for which node is known for

Comment: `Promise.all` will help you achieving this

Comment: I don't know how to write this particular thing with promises

Comment: anyways, isn't promise, just another type of callback sorta thing?

Comment: You can use async.parallel, but as I said I don't see any benefit of the async way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Promise or module async,
if you use promise, first you must convert all callback function into Promise like this:

```
const reddir = function(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      for (x in files)  console.log(files[x]);
      resolve(true);
    });
  })  
}
```

then you can use

```
Promise.all([reddir(path1), copy(path2, path3), remove(path4)])
  .spread((act1, act2, act3) => { //.spread is bluebird feature
    return writeJson(./data.json);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // all error can handled in this
  })
```

if you use async module, you can write like this:

```
async.parallel({
  act1: function(cb){
    fs.reddir(path1, (err, files) => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      for (x in files)  console.log(files[x]);
      cb(true);
    })
  },
  act2: ...
},(err, jsd) => { // jsd will be {act1: true, act2: ...}
  if (err) return console.error(err); // handle all above error here;
  fs.writeJson("./data.json", jsd, function (err, files) {
    if (err)   return console.error(err);
  });
})
```